# How to display Images from internet in a windows phone 7 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am making an application which gets urls of images by parsing an RSS feed.I want to diplay that images in the application one after another when tapped on screen .How can i do it? Is it required to download all images before displaying? Please explain.

Thanks and regards

vaysage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Parse you're RSS Feed to get the images URL's (using for exemple [HTTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))
- Set the binding for the source of each of you images (since it's web based, I recommend [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx) which will load images in the background.
- Create a SlideShow.xaml view, based on a pivot. Dynamically add Pivot items
- On tap on a thumbnail, launch the SlideShow.xaml, at the specified index

Comment: You have a Pivot template in VS2010. Each Pivot item is like a page you can slide left or right. If you put a fullscreen image on each Pivot, you have a perfect slideshow

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly but you should be able to set the Source of an Image element directly to an URI specified in your RSS feed item.

```
<Image x:Name="m_Image" Source="http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/images/ms-silverlight-logo.png"/>
```

When changing item (by tapping) you can easily swap the source of the image from your code.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("...", UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
m_Image.Source = imgSource;
```

Using LowProfileImageLoader (as mentioned by Thomas Joulin and Mick N) is a good way to load images in the background and keep the UI responsive.

Comment: when i try to add source from a url i am getting the following error :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Uri' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

Comment: Please "Mark as Answer" if this post answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get the images download in some form.

You might find these posts an interesting read.

[Keep a low profile [LowProfileImageLoader helps the Windows Phone 7 UI thread stay responsive by loading images in the background] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx)

[**There's no substitute for customer feedback! [Improving Windows Phone 7 application performance now a bit easier with LowProfileImageLoader and DeferredLoadListBox updates] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/10/04/there-s-no-substitute-for-customer-feedback-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-now-a-bit-easier-with-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)